# Javascript: Object.setup() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array ghosts of ghost objects and setup is a ghost function. Javascript does not think so...

I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: ghosts[(ghosts.length - 1)].setup is not a function

currentWords is an array of strings and setup and the new Ghost is in an interval.

```
var Ghost=function()
        {
            this.ghostPic='<img src="ghost.png">';
            this.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
            this.y=Math.floor(Math.random()*500);
            this.speed=5;
            this.width=230;
            this.height=180;
            this.firstH=2000;
            this.dead = false;
            this.word = currentWords[Math.floor(Math.random()*currentWords.length)];
        }
Ghost.prototype.setup=function()
        {
            this.ghostElement=$(this.ghostPic);
            console.log('1');
            this.ghostElement.css({
                height:this.height-=2000,
                width:this.width-=2000,
                position:"absolute",
                zIndex:-1,
                left:this.x,
                top:this.y
            });
            console.log("2");
            $('body').append(this.ghostElement);
        }
```

and then I call setup like this

```
ghosts.concat(new Ghost());
ghosts[ghosts.length-1].setup();
```

thanks!

Comment: is that ghosts is not defined as array , did you declare ghosts as var ghosts =[] ???

Comment: please share ghosts variable declaration details

Comment: @NagaSaiA I used var ghosts = []; this is the first line of my code and still getting this error with push() and splice().

Comment: show your code!! It appears that you use the array variable before you declare/initialize it.

Comment: created codepen , clearing few parameters - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JmojJJ?editors=1010 and push will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either

```
ghosts.push(new Ghost());
```

or

```
ghosts = ghosts.concat(new Ghost());
```

because `Array.prototype.concat` returns a new array, but `Array.prototype.push` changes the array.

P.S. don't forget to initialize the ghosts array (before using push or concat) as follows;

```
var ghosts = [];
```

Comment: could you try `console.log(ghosts instanceof  Array)` before the ghosts.push line

Comment: true is returned

Comment: I checked the codepen you provided and it's working, the console gives the required log.

Comment: hmm then why doesnt my code work? this is so confusing

Comment: figured it out, in line 115 `ghosts++` this should be `ctrl++`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, My Friend.

Answer (score 1):

[`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combines arrays and does not modify the existing one. Perhaps you want `ghosts.push`?

Comment: That gives me this: Uncaught TypeError: ghosts.push is not a function

Comment: @ClaytonS what type is `ghosts`?

Comment: ghosts is an array of Ghost objects. Initially its empty.